# Java - program does not write down all data (cuts 15 positions at the end) - why?

Tags: java, rgb, pixel

I am a complete newbie so maybe the question is obvious: The thing is that I am making the program (JAVA, processing) that is to give me the amount of R, G, B in each selected pixel (each pixel in each ten row) on the picture. When I am printing the outputs over the console it works perfectly all data till the 250 pixel in last row are there (picture width is 251) but when I write it down to the file it cuts the data in 235 pixel - 15 remaining are not written down. Is it the question of buffer memory? How can I have all data written?
Here is the code:

```
PrintWriter output;

void setup()

{
 output = createWriter("positions.txt");     //writedown tool enter
  size(251,201);                             // screen size setup
  PImage img = loadImage("sharp.jpg");       // implementing image Sketch->Add File
  image(img,0,0);                            // placeing the img on the screen
  loadPixels();                              // work on pixels

  for(int s=0; s < pixels.length; s=s+9*width)    // go through selected rows of pixels with intervals of 10 rows (0 to 0+9width)
  {
    for(int j=0; j < width; j++)               // go through each pixel in selected row
    {
    float r=red(pixels[s+j]);                  // read the red value from each chceked pixel
    float b=blue(pixels[s+j]);                 // read the blue value from each chceked pixel
    float g=green(pixels[j+s]);                // read the green value from each checked pixel

   output.println(j + " , "+ s +" , "+ r + " , " + g + " , " + b);  //write the data down to the file (selected data)

   color black = color(0, 0, 0);                              // checking, set a black color
   pixels[j+s]=black;                                         // checking, change the color of current pixel

  println(j + " , "+ s +" ; "+ r + " , " + g + " , " + b);    // print the read data

    }
    }
updatePixels();                                // set changes
}

void keyPressed()
{
output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
 output.close();  // Finishes the file
  exit();  // Stops the program
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try writing `output.flush();` just before `updatePixels();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the help above. Now I have to go deeper into this and I would like the program to give me also a CSV file with such agregation of the table: first column will be the y position on the tested picture, first row the x position (pixel by pixel), next row is R value, then G, then B. The thing is that I have put it into the loop for it to be done automatically but I have stacked again - **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** what I thing I shouldn't have. Here is the code:
PrintWriter output;

```
Table Tabela;
String i;
void setup()

{
 output = createWriter("positions.txt");     //writedown tool enter
 Tabela=new Table();
  size(251,201);                             // screen size setup
  PImage img = loadImage("sharp.jpg");       // implementing image Sketch->Add File
  image(img,0,0);                            // placeing the img on the screen
  loadPixels();                              // work on pixels

  for(int s=0; s < pixels.length; s=s+9*width)    // go through selected rows of pixels with intervals of 10 rows (0 to 0+9width)
  {
    for(int j=0; j < width; j++)               // go through each pixel in selected row
    {
    float r=red(pixels[s+j]);                  // read the red value from each chceked pixel
    float b=blue(pixels[s+j]);                 // read the blue value from each chceked pixel
    float g=green(pixels[j+s]);                // read the green value from each checked pixel

   Tabela.addColumn("Y");
   String i=Integer.toString(j);
   Tabela.addColumn(i);
   TableRow newRow=Tabela.addRow();
   newRow.setInt("Y", Tabela.lastRowIndex());

   newRow.setFloat(s,r);
   newRow.setFloat(s,g);
   newRow.setFloat(s,b);

   output.println(s + " , "+ j +" , "+ r + " , " + g + " , " + b);  //write the data down to the file (selected data)

   color black = color(0, 0, 0);                              // checking, set a black color
   pixels[j+s]=black;                                         // checking, change the color of current pixel

  println(s + " , "+ j +" ; "+ r + " , " + g + " , " + b);    // print the read data

    }
    }
    output.flush();
    saveTable(Tabela,"data/tabela.csv");
    updatePixels();                                // set changes
}

void keyPressed()
{
output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
 output.close();  // Finishes the file
  exit();  // Stops the program
}
```